# WSO2 external hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, wso2, wso2-bam

We want to connect our WSO2 BAM 2.0.1 to external hadoop cluster (fully distributed). I followed this link for the setup

[Configuring Apache Hive](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Configuring+Apache+Hive)

However when i run my Hive Script I get following errors

> java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

This Hive Script works fine with local Hadoop mode...

Do I need to make any changes to Hive Scripts as well when working with external Hadoop Cluster..

These are the errors I see in console..

> TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,583]  INFO {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities} -  Content Summary not cached for hdfs://r4p8n0c:9000/user/hive/warehouse_wso2-1234/aeanalyticstable_demo {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,583]  INFO {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities} -  Content Summary not cached for hdfs://r4p8n0c:9000/user/hive/warehouse_wso2-1234/aeanalyticstable_demo {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,590]  INFO {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Add a non-native table hdfs://r4p8n0c:9000/user/hive/warehouse_wso2-1234/aeanalyticstable_demo {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,590]  INFO {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Add a non-native table hdfs://r4p8n0c:9000/user/hive/warehouse_wso2-1234/aeanalyticstable_demo {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,832] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,832] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,833]  INFO {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -   {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,833]  INFO {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -   {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,833]  INFO {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -   {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,833]  INFO {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -   {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,834]  INFO {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -   {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,834]  INFO {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -   {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,834] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error while executing Hive script.
>       Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl}
>       java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
>               at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:325)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:225)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>       TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-01-16 09:42:36,848] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.ui.client.HiveExecutionClient} -  Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.ui.client.HiveExecutionClient}
>
> org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.stub.HiveExecutionServiceHiveExecutionException: HiveExecutionServiceHiveExecutionException
>               at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>               at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
>               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.stub.HiveExecutionServiceStub.executeHiveScript(HiveExecutionServiceStub.java:215)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.ui.client.HiveExecutionClient.executeScript(HiveExecutionClient.java:66)
>               at org.apache.jsp.hive_002dexplorer.queryresults_jsp._jspService(queryresults_jsp.java:90)
>               at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
>               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
>               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>               at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
>               at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
>               at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
>               at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>               at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)

Comment: It will be useful if you can mention the exceptions printed in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to have WSO2 BAM working with external Fully Distributed Hadoop.

Looks like 2.0.1 version is having troubles submitting the map-reduce job to external hadoop cluster.. We rolled backed to 2.0.0 and Hive Scripts started working.

I wanted to know if this is a known issue with 2.0.1 ? We had a stripped down version of 2.0.1 (it has only the carbon,Analytics/AnalyticsUI, Dashboard, Registry,Databridge, datasource, stratos,security, tasks and transport management features)

Thanks
Rajiv

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup the external hadoop cluster properly, it should work. It has been tested with external hadoop cluster. If you get any issue please check the error logs in hadoop cluster nodes as well. It will be helpful to find the hadoop cluster related configuration issues. Because sometimes issue showed in the ui is not very useful. 
You don't need to change the Hive scripts to work with external cluster.

Thanks,
Kasun.

Comment: The Hadoop cluster setup looks fine.. I am able to run the query from Hive cli and I can see that data from underlying Cassandra is fetched..

Comment: the hive script executed within BAM successfully defines the hive tables but as soon as the select statement is encountered it throws error code -101.. I dont see errors on the hadoop data nodes/name nodes.. In the hive-site.xml its mentioned to uncomment certain sections for pseudo distributed mode... does that mean WSO2 only supports Psuedo Distributed mode.. and not the Fully Distributed mode of hadoop ? My hadoop cluster is in Fully Distributed mode.. Any tips will be very usefull.. as I am stuck at this point .. trying to make my wso2 setup production grade